# VC Dimension of a Countably Infinite Class

Tags: machine-learning, vc-theory, pac-learning

I know that there are many examples of classes where the VC Dimension is finite/infinite even though the size of the class is **Uncountably Infinite**.

However, I could not argue if the VC Dimension of a **Countably Infinite** class is **always finite**? (I feel that its size will be "smaller" than the size of a power set of an arbitrarily large set)

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: It does no seem that countability is relevant to the VC dimension. For any uncountable examples of point sets in spaces such as R^d  you can get arbitrarily close approximations in spaces Q^d where Q are the rational numbers. Q^d are countably infinite.

Comment: Isn't the power set of Q uncountable?

Comment: Why does it matter? Concretely, in 5. of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapnik%E2%80%93Chervonenkis_dimension#Examples you should (hopefully) be able to replace $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ to $\theta \in \mathbb{Q}$ and get infinite VC-dimension with a countable family of classifiers.

Comment: Apologies for the late response - I haven't been receiving any notifications from stackexchange.
Thanks a lot. Now, I understand your point. For any arbitrarily large set, we can use rational theta and shatter the set. My doubt is cleared up. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, you shouldn't delete it. Maybe someone else finds it useful.